# Setting custom node version (path) for Neovim

Tags: node.js, macos, vim, neovim, zshrc

**TL;DR:** I'd like to use node v14 for neovim only, and v8 for everything else. Suggestions?

Hello!

I have recently started using neovim for development purposes. I have installed several plugins, some of which require higher node versions than 8 - which is mandatory for my work environment. I used nvm, downloaded latest v14. Since nvm takes a ton of time to load up, I have added path in zshrc, which I simply changed from `export PATH=../v8../bin` to `export PATH=../v14../bin`. So far, so good. But my work repos throw errors, since they require node v8.

Now, I start up nvim on v14 in a session, then manually change path in zhsrc for work sessions to v8. This seems cumbersome to do every time. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following line can be added to your `nvim/init.vim` to prepend a directory `DIR` to your `PATH` when `nvim` is launched.

```
let $PATH = 'DIR:' . $PATH
```

Here's an example with the directory you specified.

```
let $PATH = '../v14../bin:' . $PATH
```

Comment: Woah, just what I was looking for. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

Use nvim environment variable: `let g:node_host_prog = '/usr/local/bin/neovim-node-host'`

See [Neovim Provider Documentation](https://neovim.io/doc/user/provider.html)

Answer (score 0):

I came here trying to get [Github's Copilot](https://docs.github.com/en/copilot/getting-started-with-github-copilot?tool=vimneovim) working on Neovim. It requires Node 18+ (as of writing) but locally the apps I work on still use older Node versions, so I didn't want to change my default node version with `nvm alias default`.

My solution came with combining @reedmb's `node_host_prog` and finding a config for the Copilot plugin: `copilot_node_command`

In my `init.vim` I set both of those:

```
let g:node_host_prog = '~/.nvm/versions/node/v20.10.0/lib/node_modules'
let g:copilot_node_command = '~/.nvm/versions/node/v20.10.0/bin/node'
```

I found those values by using `npm root -g` and `which node` to find the relevant paths of the default version I was using and substituting the version I wanted Neovim & Copilot to use (after installing with `nvm install v20.10.0` of course)